# How to find max number of participant who can perform?

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question which has the following description:

At a time only one person can perform on the stage and arrival time and duration of each participant is given in the form of an array. Find the max number of participants who can perform.

Example:

> arrival time: [1,3,3,5,7]
>
> duration: [2,2,1,2,1]
>
> answer would be 4, as 1-3; 3-5 or 3-4; 5-7; 7-8

So from this, I can find the exit time of each participant. How do I find max number of events possible, when there is overlap in timings.

The code I have tried is:

```
int count = 1;
        
for(int i=0;i<entry.size()-1;i++) {
    if(entry.get(i) < exit.get(i+1)) {
        count++;
    }
}
        
return count;
```

I found the exit list using arrival + duration, but many tests are failing. The above example passes, but there might be instances where the overlapping time may have more participants possible.

I am not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: The problem statement is not specific enough. What should happen with the two persons arriving at 3? May they perform one after the other? Or can only one of them perform?

Comment: What is the answer to the example, and why?

Comment: @ThomasKläger only one can perform at a time,

Comment: @user3386109 I have added the answer

Comment: @user3386109 yes I also thought so, but I am a bit weak in DP and would greatly benefit from some help in this.

Comment: I do not understand, in the problem statement, what prevents everybody from performing everytime. Sure, only one person can perform at a time, so just have everybody else wait in line, and eventually, everybody will have performed. What rule prevents this ?

Comment: @GPI the duration one, that rule states that the performer will leave after a fixed time.

Comment: So “duration” means both how much time the act needs AND when will the performer leave ?

Comment: Is their still something wrong with my answer ? I think I meet all your criteria. If its correct you can flag it as the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated answer as a new test case was added which made it clear the performers can be reordered if they have the same arrival time.
2nd update: Sort the input on the end time of each performer (arrival+duration).
Keep the endTime of the current performer. Only performers can perform which arrive after the end of the current performer.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class LifeGig {

    public static class Performer {
        int arrival, duration;

        Performer(int arrival, int duration) {
            this.arrival = arrival;
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Performer [arrival=" + arrival + ", duration=" + duration + "]";
        }
    }

    public List<Performer> program(int[] entry,int[] duration)
    {
        List<Performer> performers=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<entry.length;i++)
        {
            performers.add(new Performer(entry[i],duration[i]));
        }
        Collections.sort(performers, new Comparator<Performer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Performer p1, Performer p2) {
                return Integer.compare(p1.arrival+p1.duration, p2.arrival+p2.duration);
            }
        });
        List<Performer> festival=new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(performers);
        int currentTime = 1;
        for (Performer p:performers) {
            if (p.arrival >= currentTime) {
                currentTime = p.arrival+p.duration;
                festival.add(p);
            }
        }
        return festival;
    }
    public static void test1()
    {
        int[] entry = new int[] {1,3,3,5,7};
        int[] duration = new int[] {2,2,1,2,1};
        List<Performer> festival=new LifeGig().program(entry,duration);
        System.out.println("Count (Expected=4): " + festival.size());
        System.out.println("lineup:"+festival);
    }

    public static void test2()
    {
        int[] entry = new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 4};
        int[] duration = new int[] {10, 3, 6, 4, 2};
        List<Performer> festival=new LifeGig().program(entry,duration);
        System.out.println("Count (Expected=2): " + festival.size());
        System.out.println("lineup:"+festival);
    }
    public static void test3()
    {
        int[] entry = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
        int[] duration = new int[] {10, 1,1,1,};
        List<Performer> festival=new LifeGig().program(entry,duration);
        System.out.println("Count (Expected=3): " + festival.size());
        System.out.println("lineup:"+festival);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test1();
        test2();
        test3();
    }

}
```

Comment: Still some test cases are failing for example:
[1,1,1,1,4] and durations [10,3,6,4,2] should give 2 but this gives 1

Comment: Won't this fail when you have something like this [1,2, 3, 4] and durations [10, 1, 1, 1]? Should give 3 but gives 1

Answer (score 1):

Since OP asked for a DP solution in a comment, and because it's not proven by the accepted answer that the greedy choice leads to an optimal solution, here's a DP solution. For any event, either it takes place or doesn't. The answer is the maximum of the two choices.

```
public class Solution {
    private final List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> events;
    private final int[] startTimes;
    private final Map<Integer, Integer> memo;
    private static final Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> COMPARATOR =
            Comparator.<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>comparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue);

    public Solution(int[] arrivals, int[] durations) {
        events = IntStream.range(0, arrivals.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(arrivals[i], arrivals[i] + durations[i]))
                .sorted(COMPARATOR)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        startTimes = events.stream()
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .toArray();

        memo = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private int loop(int i) {
        if (i >= startTimes.length) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (memo.containsKey(i)) {
            return memo.get(i);
        }
        int ans = loop(i + 1);
        int nextI = Arrays.binarySearch(startTimes, events.get(i).getValue());
        if (nextI < 0) {
            nextI = -nextI - 1;
        }
        ans = Math.max(ans, 1 + loop(nextI));
        memo.put(i, ans);
        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Solution(new int[]{1, 3, 3, 5, 7}, new int[]{2, 2, 1, 2, 1}).loop(0));
        System.out.println(new Solution(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1, 4}, new int[]{10, 3, 6, 4, 2}).loop(0));
        System.out.println(new Solution(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, new int[]{10, 1, 1, 1}).loop(0));
    }
}
```